# sap.m.MessageBox.confirm working sap.m.MessageBox.error or sap.m.MessageBox.warning not working

Tags: sapui5, messagebox

In my sapui5 project i am using `sap.m.MessageBox.confirm` its working fine but when i use `sap.m.MessageBox.error` or `sap.m.MessageBox.warning` it shows error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I have added `jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");` still the issue is not solved. please give solution for this problem

Thanks

Sorry for not posting the code earlier

**Edited 1**

**View**

```
 <core:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m"
        controllerName="trial.S1" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <Page title="Title">
        <content>

        </content>
        <footer>
            <OverflowToolbar>
                <ToolbarSpacer />
                <Button id="errorId" text="Error" type="Accept"
                    press="fnOnerror" />    
                    <Button id="confirmId" text="Confirm" type="Accept"
                    press="fnOnconfirm" />  
            </OverflowToolbar>
        </footer>
    </Page>
</core:View>
```

**Conroller**

```
jQuery.sap.require("sap.m.MessageBox");
sap.ui.controller("trial.S1", {
    fnOnerror : function(oEvent){

         sap.m.MessageBox.error("My error message");

    },
    fnOnconfirm : function(oEvent){
        sap.m.MessageBox.confirm("My Confirm message")
    }

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
        </script>
        <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

        <script>
                sap.ui.localResources("trial");
                var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"idS11"});
                var page = sap.ui.view({id:"idS11", viewName:"trial.S1", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML});
                app.addPage(page);
                app.placeAt("content");
        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need to see more code. Or a minimum working example (JSBin/JSFiddle). It is very unlikely that some functions are loaded and others are not. The error is probably somewhere else, try running your code through http://jshint.com/ or similar sites to see all its errors.

Comment: sorry, i have added code now

Comment: This is still not the complete code. Please also post your bootstrap (i.e. index.html) etc. Also, like @Marc has suggested, post example code that is at least runnable for reproducing the issue, i.e. via jsbin, jsFiddle, or even directly here on stackoverflow!

Comment: i have recreated the issue and posted it. i can't post original code due to some internal issues. i have recreated that issue and posted the code please verify it and give  solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How should we give you a solution for your issue if your information is not enough? From what you describe it is hard to tell what you are doing wrong. Make sure to always add more information including code.

After getting the information from you we know now that you are using version 1.28.9 of UI5. If you would have checked the API docs at https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MessageBox.html#.error then you would have known that the APIs you are using were introduced in 1.30!!!

Comment: @sarathchambayil please post more code, including bootstrap/index.html etc.!!!!! I updated my example code according to your example code and it still works just fine!

Comment: i have posted the code with index, i am getting same issue

Comment: what version of ui5 are you using?

Comment: I updated the answer. If you would have checked the API docs at https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MessageBox.html#.error then you would have known that the APIs you are using were introduced in 1.30!!! So they are not available in 1.28.x!!! Next time post all relevant information! Also check the API docs! By the way: in your bootstrap change the src attribute to either https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js or https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.32.8/resources/sap-ui-core.js in order to see what happens!

Comment: I appreciate all your elaborated answers, but this one would be better off without the code examples. The core point of the answer (version issue) gets lost..